# Someone other than OP awarded bounty to answer with less votes ie OP didn't award it

Tags: discussion, bounties

Update, I made an honest mistake. I assumed the person who set the bounty was the person who asked the question, this was my mistake. Thanks to Kendra for pointing it out in the comments and how to find out who posted the bounty.

Comment: The asker did not create the bounty. Someone else did. The person who creates the bounty gets to award it. Only the checkmark is reserved to the asker.

Comment: Why is it wrong for them to award the bounty to the answer they feel best answers the question?  If we wanted the bounty to always go to the highest voted answer there wouldn't be an option for users to select who the bounty is awarded to in the first place.

Comment: The bounty wasn't started by the OP. The person who starts the bounty gets to pick which answer gets the full bounty (or let the bounty be auto-awarded for half the amount.) See the [bounty page in the help center](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) as it explains how bounties work.

Comment: Also note that the awarded answer _is five days newer than yours_ and may have had a higher score had it been posted the same day as yours. A couple days can make that difference in scores.

Comment: I'm checking my facts, I thought the OP set the bounty, this might be wrong. I'll clarify and get back.

Comment: You can check [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36667502/revisions) The revision history for a question shows that information.

Comment: I didn't know that existed. I can see now that the OP didn't start the bounty ie my question is moot.

Comment: For future reference, you can get to the revision history by clicking the "edited x ago" link on a question, or altering the url to replace "questions" with "posts" and the title part to "revisions". For example, to see it on your meta post here you would change `questions/279236/someone-other-than-op-awarded-bounty-to-answer-with-less-votes-ie-op-didnt-awar` to `posts/279236/revisions`.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, let's set things straight. That user took some of their reputation to start a bounty on a question where you happened to have an answer. The community appreciated your answer and the answer of another user.

The user who started the bounty found the other answer more helpful than yours, so he decided that that answer earned his reputation the most.

What did the user raising the bounty do wrong here? Nothing. So why would you need auto object to his decision? I don't know.

That particular user was very clear in the [reason he picked that other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667502/why-does-perls-print-fail-to-output-anything-to-stdout-and-stderr-but-writes-t#comment61872270_37095268) too.

Comment: I made a mistake, I assumed the setter of the bounty was the original poster. I only learned about being able to find who set the bounty after I asked this question. Thanks to Kendra things were perfectly straight before you posted this answer but now instead I'm going to get berated for what I think is an honest mistake, this is the sort of thing that's slowly putting me off SO as a contributor. Honest mistakes get jumped on and you end up feeling like crap because of it, thanks. Please feel free to keep kicking.

Comment: Even if the poster of the question was also the bounty raiser, why do you want to force him to pick your answer? Simply because it has two extra votes? What if the other answer was just better?

Comment: I don't want to force him to pick anything. I thought... mistakenly... that someone who was not the bounty raiser was able to award the bounty ie they had some sort of moderator privilege that allowed them to do it. if I'd known the bounty had been awarded by the same person that raised it I would never have asked this question.